# Libsvm and Python : Precomputed Kernels are using my point id as a normal feature?

Tags: python, libsvm

I have a strange problem with libsvm and the usage of precomputed kernels.
I have put my data in a dictionnary form to follow the documentation (key 0 associated to the point id):

```
from svmutil import *

x=[]
for i in range(N):
    x[i] = {0:i, 1:K(i,0), 2:K(i,1), ...}
    y[i] = true_labels(i)
```

)
Then, I am doing the following to train the svm and get my training error:

```
svm_prob = svm_problem(y,x,isKernel=True)
svm_param = svm_parameter('-t 4')
svm_mod = libsvm.svm_train(svm_prob,svm_param)
svm_pymod = toPyModel(svm_mod)

# Estimating training error
p_labels, p_acc, p_val = svm_predict(y,x,svm_pymod)
```

But the final output is completely incorrect since the values p_val look like:

```
p_val -> [0.xxx, -1.xxx, -2.xxx, -3.xxx, -4.xxx, ...]
```

(and the p_labels are of course `[-1,-1,-1,...,]`)

My analysis:
I know that the values of my kernel `K(i,j)` are far below 1 so I think that the pseudo-feature `(0:i)` has been used at some point (probably in the prediction stage) by libsvm as a normal feature (and not as the point id).
I have tried several variations but I am unable to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help or comments on my code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was quite obvious actually but I keep my post and answer it here:
The point id has to start at `1` and not at `0`. The low-level function `libsvm.svm_train`does not check this and solves the problem with this incorrect setting.

One should use instead the`svmutil` function "`svm_train`" that displays an error in this case.

Once this starting index has been corrected, the classifier seems to work normally.